# Download an exe from google drive using wget

Tags: cmd, google-drive-api, wget

Is there any way to download a file from google drive using command? Whenever I try to do it, it downloads the contents of the website, not the exe. I'm making an auto-downloader, which whenever pressed will download the most recent patch. Help!

Comment: You need to start with authentication first. Everything is described here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices

and here's how you could get the right download url for your drive file
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-downloads

Comment: @gRenzFries, you should post your comment as an answer, so this question shows as "answered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using wget:

```
wget --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID' -O FILENAME
```

But I use another way to download files and folder, because if you will change file it will be with new file id.

Try to use: https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive for Windows/Linux/Mac

Using drive.exe:

```
drive download --id 0B3X9GlR6EmbnenBYSFI4MzN0d2M
```

And, for downloading folder I write BAT file

```
@echo off
::USAGE: PATH\TO\THISFILE.BAT "ID"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set DRIVEBAT=%PROGRAMFILES%\Google Drive Downloader\drivefolder.bat
set DRIVECONF=%PROGRAMFILES%\Google Drive Downloader\.gdrive
if "%1"=="" exit
set FOLDERID=%1
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`drive -c "%DRIVECONF%" info -i %FOLDERID% ^| find "Title: "`) do (
    set "FOLDERNAME=%%a"
    set "FOLDERNAME=!FOLDERNAME:Title: =!"
    echo Downloading [!FOLDERNAME!] dir...
)
rd /s /q !FOLDERNAME! >nul 2>&1
md "!FOLDERNAME!\"
cd "!FOLDERNAME!\"

for /f "usebackq tokens=1" %%a in (`drive -c "%DRIVECONF%" list -q "'%FOLDERID%' in parents" -n`) do (
    drive -c "%DRIVECONF%" download -i %%a >nul || (
        echo.
        timeout /t 3 >nul 2>&1
        start "" cmd.exe /c call "%DRIVEBAT%" "%%a"
    )
)
exit
```

Install bat:

1. set DRIVEBAT=%PROGRAMFILES%\Google Drive Downloader\drivefolder.bat
2. set DRIVECONF=%PROGRAMFILES%\Google Drive Downloader\.gdrive
3. add to windows variable PATH %PROGRAMFILES%\Google Drive Downloader\
4. copy drive config from %appdata%\roaming\.gdrive
5. copy drive.exe to %PROGRAMFILES%\Google Drive Downloader\

Usage bat:

```
cmd.exe /c cd "C:\destenetionfolder" & call "drivefolder.bat" "0FG6kgDTKrk6ERKTY45klDHdldGc"
```